# Return every N-th word of a string

Tags: code-golf, string

Your goal is to write a program that, given a number *N* and a string as input, will return a string containing every *N*th word of the original string, starting from the first word.

Sample inputs/outputs:

```
N = 2, str = "This is a sentence"

"This a"
--
N = 2, str = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."

"The brown jumped the dog."
--
N = 7, str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa."

"Lorem elit. massa."
```

You're allowed to assume that the input will always contain at least *N+1* words, and that words will always be delimited by the space character `&#32;`.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: The I/O seems to be underspecified. Are we supposed to read `N = 2, str = "This is a sentence"` from STDIN?

Comment: @Dennis I intentionally left it vague. Take input in whatever way you want; stdin, reading from a file, speech-to-text...

Comment: Should have posted first and asked questions later. This contest is already over...

Comment: This is a bit too easy IMO... This just becomes a fastest gun in the west contest.

Comment: Also, what the hell? Don't accept an answer within 20 minutes! A contest must run for at least a week to allow other submissions.

Comment: @orlp: I've undone it; I thought that I should change it if another shorter one comes along. This was my first attempt at a contest, prolly should've used the sandbox first.

Comment: What are the possible word separators?

Comment: @LuisMendo Space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Pyth, 6

```
jd%Qcz
```

Splits on spaces, takes every Nth element, joins on spaces.

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jd%25Qcz&input=Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%2C+consectetuer+adipiscing+elit.+Aenean+commodo+ligula+eget+dolor.+Aenean+massa.%0A7)

## Explanation

```
jd          : join on spaces
  %Q        : take every Qth character (Q will have read the input with N)
    cz      : chop the other input on whitespace
```

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 7 bytes

```
q~S/%S*
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~S%2F%25S*&input=7%20%22Lorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet%2C%20consectetuer%20adipiscing%20elit.%20Aenean%20commodo%20ligula%20eget%20dolor.%20Aenean%20massa.%22) This reads a number and a string (in that order) from STDIN.

### Explanation

```
q~      e# Read and eval input.
  S/    e# Split on spaces.
    %   e# Take every Nth element.
     S* e# Join the words back together with spaces.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 35 characters

```
lambda n,s:' '.join(s.split()[::n])
```

Comment: It should be a string, not a list, as per the examples.

Comment: Whoops, that's right. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## KDB(Q), 26 bytes

```
{" "sv#[0N,y;" "vs x][;0]}
```

## Explanation

```
             " "vs x         / cut x string by space
      #[0N,y;       ]        / cut list by y length
                     [;0]    / take first of each list
 " "sv                       / combine with space
{                        }   / lambda
```

## Test

```
q){" "sv#[0N,y;" "vs x][;0]}["The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";2]
"The brown jumped the dog."
```

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 38 bytes

```rb
(n,s)->join(split(s," ")[1:n:end]," ")
```

This creates an anonymous function that accepts an integer and string as input and returns the required output. To call it, give it a name, e.g. `f=(n,s)->...`.

Ungolfed + explanation:

```rb
function f(n, s)
    # Split the string into words
    words = split(s, " ")

    # Get every nth word starting at 1
    every_nth = words[1:n:end]

    # Join into a single string separated with a space
    join(every_nth, " ")
end
```

Examples:

```rb
julia> f(2, "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.")
"The brown jumped the dog."

julia> f(2, "This is a sentence.")
"This a"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes (language postdates challenge?)

```
ḲmK
```

`Ḳ` splits the first input on spaces; `m` takes every nth element; then `K` joins on spaces again. `m` is missing a second argument, so it takes the second input by default.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wx6Zc7////4dkpCoUlmYmZyskFeWX5ymk5VcoZJXmFqSmKOSXpRYplADlcxKrKhVS8tP1/hsBAA)

Answer (score 0):

## 12-basic, 42 bytes

```
?JOIN(INPUT$().SPLIT(" ")STEP INPUT()," ")
```

[Try](https://12me21.github.io/12-basic/#Ttextarea%3B%3FJOIN(INPUT%24().SPLIT(%22%20%22)STEP%20INPUT()%2C%22%20%22)%7ET%23%5C%24input%3BLorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet%2C%20consectetuer%20adipiscing%20elit.%20Aenean%20commodo%20ligula%20eget%20dolor.%20Aenean%20massa.%0A7%7ECbutton)